# Count number of individual operations

Tags: algebra, counting

Im interested in counting the number of operations required to evaluate a given formula. Let me give you an example.

Lets say I have entered the expression $\dfrac{\operatorname{Sqrt}[\operatorname{Sin}[a*x+b*x-c*y]]}{2*a+b}$

Now lets say you have values for those unknows $a,b,c$. Then you would to calculate $a*x+b*x-c*y$ first which requires 3 multiplications, 1 addition and 1 subtraction. Then you take the $\sin(...)$ and then the square root.

Now you might calculate $2*a+b$ which requires 1 multiplication and 1 addition. In the end you take the quotient. This gives a total number of:

$1\times\sin, 1\times\sqrt{\cdot} \ 1 \times$ quotient, $4 \times $ multiplication, $2 \times$ addition and 1 subtraction.

Well you might call one subtraction the result of 1 multiplication and 1 addition. But that doesnt matter to me.

Since I have most of my formulas stored in Mathematica it would be great to have such a function. That would save a lot of time counting by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the output of `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression ``? For your example:

```
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[
    Sqrt[Sin[a x + b x - c y]]/(2 a + b), 
    "OptimizationLevel"->2
]
```

```
Experimental`OptimizedExpression[
   Block[{Compile`$34, Compile`$35, Compile`$36, Compile`$37, Compile`$38, Compile`$39, Compile`$40, Compile`$41, Compile`$42}, 
      Compile`$34 = 2 a; 
      Compile`$35 = Compile`$34 + b; 
      Compile`$36 = 1/Compile`$35;
          Compile`$37 = a x; 
      Compile`$38 = b x; 
      Compile`$39 = -c y; 
          Compile`$40 = Compile`$37 + Compile`$38 + Compile`$39; 
      Compile`$41 = Sin[Compile`$40]; 
          Compile`$42 = Sqrt[Compile`$41]; 
      Compile`$36 Compile`$42
   ]
]
```

A version using it might be something like:

```
opCount[expr_] := Extract[
    Experimental`OptimizeExpression[expr, "OptimizationLevel"->2],
    {1,1},
    Length
] + 1

opCount[Sqrt[Sin[a x + b x - c y]]/(2 a + b)]
```

> 10

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this gets you exactly what you want, but I found this in the documentation for `LeafCount`:

```
expr = Sqrt[Sin[a x + b x - c y]]/(2 a + b)
leaves = Level[expr, {-1}, Heads -> True]
Tally[leaves]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Times} & 5 \\
 \text{Power} & 2 \\
 \text{Plus} & 2 \\
 2 & 1 \\
 a & 2 \\
 b & 2 \\
 -1 & 2 \\
 \text{Sin} & 1 \\
 x & 2 \\
 c & 1 \\
 y & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Like you mentioned, subtraction is dealt with as a multiplication of a negative number and addition. Also I'm not sure if this is a deal-breaker, but division is dealt with as a multiplication with $(2a+b)^{-1}$ and the square root is dealt with as `Power[..., Rational[1, 2]]`.

You could filter the resulting tally a bit with

```
Select[Tally[leaves], Or @@ Thread[#[[1]] == {Sin, Times, Power, Plus}] &]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Times} & 5 \\
 \text{Power} & 2 \\
 \text{Plus} & 2 \\
 \text{Sin} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$